# c compiler, overlap memory error

Tags: c, memory-management

Below is a portion of the C code I am using:

```
pushbutton_ISR()
{

    int press;
    int key_pressed;

    press = *(KEYS_ptr + 3);                // read the pushbutton Edge Det Register interrupt register
    *(KEYS_ptr + 3) = 0;                    // Clear the Edge Det registers. 

    if (press & 0x1) {                      // KEY1
        key_pressed = KEY1;
        //sum = sum + *NEW_NUMBER; 
        }
    else if (press & 0x2)   {               // KEY2
        key_pressed = KEY2;
        *GREEN_LEDS = *NEW_NUMBER;
         sum = sum + *NEW_NUMBER;
        *RED_LEDS = sum;
        }
    else                                    // i.e. (press & 0x8), which is KEY3
        sum = *(NEW_NUMBER);                // Read the SW slider switch values; store in pattern

    return;
}
```

The compiler compiles this fine and the code appears to run (on an Altera board) fine. However, when I change the first `if` statement to:

```
if (press & 0x1) {                      // KEY1
    //key_pressed = KEY1;
    sum = sum + *NEW_NUMBER; 
}
```

the compiler gives the following error messages:

```
.../nios2-elf/bin/ld.exe: section .data loaded at [00000a00,00000e0f] overlaps section .text loaded at [00000500,00000a0f]
.../nios2-elf/bin/ld.exe: section .ctors loaded at [00000a10,00000a13] overlaps section .data loaded at [00000a00,00000e0f]
.../nios2-elf/bin/ld.exe: Z:/Projects/Altera/3215_W15_LabB/Part2/from_handout.elf: section .data vma 0xa00 overlaps previous sections
.../nios2-elf/bin/ld.exe: Z:/Projects/Altera/3215_W15_LabB/Part2/from_handout.elf: section .ctors vma 0xa10 overlaps previous sections
.../nios2-elf/bin/ld.exe: Z:/Projects/Altera/3215_W15_LabB/Part2/from_handout.elf: section .rodata vma 0xa14 overlaps previous sections
.../nios2-elf/bin/ld.exe: Z:/Projects/Altera/3215_W15_LabB/Part2/from_handout.elf: section .sdata vma 0xe10 overlaps previous sections
.../nios2-elf/bin/ld.exe: Z:/Projects/Altera/3215_W15_LabB/Part2/from_handout.elf: section .sbss vma 0xe18 overlaps previous sections
```

Could you please advise me about the reasons for these errors, and how to resolve them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with your code being incorrect.

These are linker errors (it even tells you `ld.exe` is the program complaining) about output sections overlapping.  This *probably* means you just ran out of space, but could also mean the linker directive file your project is using has some problems.

Answer (score 0):

When you add in this line, it causes the size of the compiled code to be too big for the memory area that you are loading the code into.

You can see from the first line of the linker error message that `.text` (the code) is loaded at `0x500`, and `.data` (the non-zero static variables) is loaded at `0xa00`.  However, the .text section is so long that it is too big to fit in the space between `0x500` and `0xa00`.

To fix this you will either need to:

- Make your code smaller
- Increase the amount of space available for `.text`

To do the first one, you could use `-Os` or similar compiler option to compile for minimum code size ; or manually rewrite your code to be smaller.

For the second one you really need to understand the hardware you are loading the code into. Is it a hardware requirement that code goes at `0x500` and data goes at `0xa00`?  If not, then you may be able to load the code and/or data into different addresses.

These addresses are configured in your linker script (this may be hardcoded into the makefile or it may be an actual file somewhere). Hopefully the hardware device came with documentation that explains how much memory it has and where you're allowed to load your code to.

Comment: Thanks for the info I was looking for. I had flexibility to adjust where .text and .data could go. This fixed the issue I had. However while trying this out, once I got 'overlap error' due to .ctors. What is .ctors? On another try, the code compiled, but when downloading to the board, I got memory verification error, after memory had been downloaded. Why this would have occurred? BTW the RAM is 4KB, and as per compiler, the code is 3KB.

Comment: Never mind about the .ctors. Google helped there. Though I don't get why memory download worked, but the verification not, in the context of the mentioned issue. Thanks again.

Comment: Did you fix all the overlap messages?  Maybe the addresses you assigned actually are not valid for the hardware. There should be documentation that came with the system describing this.